# Node.js Does Not Capture All Output from Asynchronous C++ .exe File

Tags: c++, node.js, asynchronous, stdout, child-process

Stack Overflow community!

I'm encountering an issue when interfacing Node.js with asynchronous C++ code. I have an executable file written in C++ and compiled into a .exe, which utilizes asynchronous code. Specifically, some data is output from an asynchronous function that executes after all subsequent `cout` and similar commands in the code.

The problem is that when running this .exe file from Node.js using, for example, `child_process.exec` or `child_process.spawn`, not all output is being captured by Node.js. It seems that the data generated by the asynchronous function is not making it into the output stream that Node.js is able to capture.

Here is a simplified C++ code example that demonstrates this problem:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process')
const os = require('os')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

let fetch

import('node-fetch').then(module => {
    fetch = module.default
})

const Router = require('koa-router')
const router = new Router()
let apiScript = null

let accumulatedData = ""

let resolveScriptOutput

function waitForScriptResponse() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolveScriptOutput = resolve
    })
}

const ensureScriptRunning = async () => {
    if (apiScript) return

    const platform = os.platform()

    try {
        if (platform === 'linux') {
            apiScript = spawn('bash', ['-c', './TestApp'], { stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe'] })
        } else if (platform === 'win32') {
            apiScript = spawn('ConsoleScrach', [], { stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe'] })
            // apiScript = spawn(path.join(process.resourcesPath, 'ConsoleScrach.exe'), [], { stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe'] })
        } else {
            console.error("Unsupported OS platform")
            return
        }

        apiScript.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
            console.error(`Ошибка скрипта: ${data}`)
        })

        apiScript.on('close', (code) => {
            console.log(`Процесс скрипта завершен с кодом ${code}`)
            apiScript = null; // Позволяет перезапустить процесс при следующем запросе
        })


        apiScript.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
            const outputData = data.toString().trim();
            console.log(`Получены данные от скрипта в: ${new Date().getHours()}:${new Date().getMinutes()}:${new Date().getSeconds()}`)
            console.log('Получены данные от скрипта:', outputData);

            accumulatedData += outputData;

            const jsonMatch = outputData.match(/{[\s\S]*}/);
            if (jsonMatch) {
                try {
                    const jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonMatch[0])
                    if (resolveScriptOutput) {
                        resolveScriptOutput(jsonObject)
                        resolveScriptOutput = null
                    }

                    // Очистите accumulatedData после успешного разбора JSON
                    accumulatedData = ""
                } catch (parseError) {
                    console.error('Ошибка при попытке разобрать JSON:', parseError)
                    if (resolveScriptOutput) {
                        resolveScriptOutput({ error: 'Invalid JSON received' })
                        resolveScriptOutput = null
                    }
                }
            } else {
                console.warn('Не найдено строк JSON в выводе');
            }
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Ошибка при запуске или обработке скрипта:', error)
    }
}

router.post('/send-command', async (ctx) => {

    const requestBody = JSON.stringify(ctx.request.body)
    await ensureScriptRunning()
    console.log('Отправка команды:', requestBody)
    console.log(ctx.request.body)
    try {
        apiScript.stdin.write(requestBody + '\n', (err) => {
            console.log(`Команда отправлена в исполняемый файл в: ${new Date().getHours()}:${new Date().getMinutes()}:${new Date().getSeconds()}`)
            if (err) {
                console.error('Ошибка при записи в stdin:', err)
                ctx.status = 500
                ctx.body = { error: 'Ошибка при отправке команды' }
                return
            }
        })

        const scriptResponse = await waitForScriptResponse()

        ctx.body = scriptResponse
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Произошла ошибка при обработке запроса:', error)
        ctx.status = 500
        ctx.body = { error: 'Внутренняя ошибка сервера' }
    }
})
```

```cpp
case 4: {
    std::cout << "Starting case 4 start" << std::flush;
    unsigned char comadStartEnd[] = { 0x07};
    DWORD dwSize = sizeof(comadStartEnd);
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    SendComTread(comadStartEnd, dwSize, dwBytesWritten);
    std::cout << "Starting case 4 SendComTread end" << std::flush;


This SendComTread
void SendComTread(unsigned char* data, DWORD dwSize, DWORD dwBytesWritten)
{
    BOOL iRet;

    std::string message;

    message += "SendComTread start";

    uint8_t* SendBuff = new uint8_t[(dwSize + 4) * 2]{};
    uint8_t* SendBuff2 = new uint8_t[(dwSize + 4) * 2]{ 0 };
    memcpy(SendBuff, data, dwSize);

    uint8_t crc = Crc8(SendBuff, dwSize);
    memcpy(SendBuff + dwSize, &crc, sizeof(uint8_t));

    int pos = cobsEncode(SendBuff, dwSize + 1, SendBuff2 + 1);

    iRet = WriteFile(hSerial, SendBuff2, pos + 2, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

    message += std::to_string(iRet);
    message += "SendComTread end";

    std::cout << message << std::flush;
}
```

I expected to see all the program's output, including the SendComTread line, but this line is missing in stdout when I run it from Node.js. However, if I run the .exe file directly from the command line, all the output displays correctly.

How can I ensure that all output, including asynchronous, is correctly captured by Node.js?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!